# How to deploy a project using docker with gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm fairly new to docker and gitlab-ci with the docker runner.

The docker runner works and I'm fine with it except of one thing. It seems as if the docker runner cannot see locally available images. Which means I may have to create a custom registry unless there's a way to make the docker command to check on the host docker.

What I try to achieve is this:

1. Build a `Dockerfile` and fetch a few other git repositories to
2. Create a new docker image based on the `Dockerfile`.
3. Start a new docker container on the host docker which will remain alive even after the job is done.

In other words, I'm trying to generate a docker image and start/replace an existing service in the host's dockerd service.

Right now that's what I came with but it doesn't work as data isn't passed from one job to the other. And even if job build would work I doubt the docker service I created would be accessible from the outside world.

```
stages:
    - test
    - prepare
    - build

# Build the Dockerfile 
prepare_script:
  stage: prepare
  image: debian:stretch
  script:

    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y git python3
    - python3 prepare_project.py

# Build and deploy the docker image
build:
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t my-project .
    - docker run --add-host db:172.17.42.1 -d --name my-project-inst --restart always -p 8069:8069 myproject
```

How can I use gitlab-ci to automatically deploy docker images in the host docker service?

The problem I'm trying to solve is to generate the docker file so fetching of git repositories and submodules can be done dynamically without having to hand modify Dockerfiles.

Comment: Have you mounted the dock.socket in the gitlab-runner?                             
         volumes = ["/cache","/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I found out later. The most important point is to have the socket available and an image with docker installed. There was also an issue with docker trying to fetch first while setting it to fetch only if not present make it use local images.